# How many possible sets exist for $\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c = \frac12$?

Tags: geometry

Sorry for the confusing title, but I don't know any other way to present the problem.

My problem is that in a competition math book, the problem is to find how many different sets of $3$ regular polygons can be placed around a point such that the three polygons surround the point entirely, basically their interior angles add to 360 degrees around the point.

I've did some algebra and found $\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c = \frac12$.

(Sorry for the lack of formatting. I am in a rush at the moment. If somebody can help me format this, thanks!)

$a,b,$ and $c$ represent the number of sides each regular polygon has. I'm not going to explain what the equation above means and how it relates to the problem I am working on, as it's not important for this question I am asking, but I am seeking how many possibilities for the set $(a,b,c)$ exists if I give a random solution for the variable a, and I wish to solve for what b and c are.

So far, if $a = 3$, I've found two different sets of $(a,b,c)$, which are $(3,9,18)$ and $(3,12,12)$.

Please don't solve the math book question for me. **My question is how do I know how many sets of $(a,b,c)$ exist for $\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c = \frac12$.** Right now, I am giving a random solution for a and solving for b and c by guessing and checking.

If anybody can help, that would be great. Thanks!

*Also, it would be nice if you can tell me how to find the number of possibilities of the set $(a,b,c)$.*

Comment: Because of the symmetry, you can assume $a \le b \le c$.  If $a \gt 6$ you can't get a large enough sum. You can't have $a=2$ or the sum is too large. So try $a=3,4,5$ as casework.  For $a=3$ you need $\frac 1b + \frac 1c=\frac 16$ and you must have $b \le 12$

Comment: Are $a$, $b$ and $c$ required to be integers? Because your examples suggest so, but you don't say so.

Comment: This looks a lot like https://projecteuler.net/problem=108 where a solution is to let $x/y = s/t$, and solving you see that each solution comes from all cases where $s|n$, $t|n$, and $gcd(s,t)=1$.  This has 3 variables instead of 2 though so I don't know how similar it will be.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, the number of sides of a regular polygon has to be integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exhaustive search
(which I just did
by hand)
for all positive integral
solutions to

$\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c = \frac12
$

I get that all solutions are

$a=3, (b, c) = 
(7, 42), (8, 24), (9, 18),
(10, 15), (12, 12)
$.

$a=4, (b, c) =
(5, 20), (6, 12), (8, 8)
$.

$a=5, (b, c) = (5, 10)
$.

$a=6, (b, c) =
(4, 12), (6, 6)
$.

Assume
$a \le b \le c$.

Then
$\frac{3}{c}
\le\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c
\le \frac{3}{a}
$,
so
$\frac{3}{a}
\ge \frac12
\ge \frac{3}{c}
$
or
$a \le 6 \le c
$.

Similarly
$\frac12
\gt \frac1{a}
$
so
$a > 2$
or
$a \ge 3$.

Now, cases.

If
$a = 3$,
then
$\frac1{b}+\frac1{c}
= \frac12-\frac13
=\frac16
$.

If
$\frac1{b}+\frac1{c}
= \frac12-\frac13
=\frac16
$,
then
$6(b+c) = bc$
or
$36
=bc-6(b+c)+36
=(b-6)(c-6)
$.
The possible factors of $36$ are
$(1, 36), (2, 18), (3, 12),
(4, 9), (6, 6)
$
which gives
$(b, c)
=(7, 42), (8, 24), (9, 18),
(10, 15), (12, 12)
$.

If $a=4$
then
$\frac1{b}+\frac1{c}
= \frac12-\frac14
=\frac14
$.

If
$\frac1{b}+\frac1{c}
=\frac14
$,
then
$4(b+c) = bc$
or
$16
=bc-4(b+c)+16
=(b-4)(c-4)
$.
The possible factors of $16$ are
$(1, 16), (2, 8), (4, 4)$
which gives
$(b, c)
(5, 20), (6, 12), (8, 8)
$.

If $a=5$
then
$\frac1{b}+\frac1{c}
= \frac12-\frac15
=\frac{3}{10}
$
so that
$10(b+c) = 3bc$
or
$30(b+c) = 9bc$.
Since
$(3b-10)(3c-10)
=9bc-30(b+c)+100$,
this gives
$(3b-10)(3c-10)
=100$.
The factors of $100$ are
$(1, 100), (2, 50), 
(4, 25), (5, 20),
(10, 10)
$
so
$(3b, 3c) =
(11, 110), (12, 60), 
(14, 35), (15, 30),
(20, 20)
$.
The only one
which give integral $(b, c)$
with $b \ge a$ are
$(b, c)
= (5, 10)
$.

If $a=6$
then
$\frac1{b}+\frac1{c}
= \frac12-\frac16
=\frac13
$
so that
$3(b+c) = bc$
or
$(b-3)(c-3) = 9$.
The only factors of 
$9$ are
$(1, 9), (3, 3)$
so
$(b, c)
=(4, 12), (6, 6)
$.

Comment: You should delete the $(5, 4, 20)$ solution as it has $b<a$

Comment: @martycohen Thank you, kind user! You helped me find all the possible solutions, though I did not ask for them,but rather the number of them. I appreciate your hard work though! :)

Comment: @Mr. Star: I don't think that you can count the solutions without generating them all. If you can, I would be very surprised.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to Egyptian fractions.  For results of the form $4/n$ or $5/n$, it's actually an unsolved question as to where there is always a solution.   For 1/2 (or 4/8 or 5/10), a proof by exhaustion is possible.

Ten solutions. One hint is to let $a$ be the smallest number, and $b$ the second smallest.  Can $a$ be 7 or higher?

[Unsolved Conjectures about Egyptian Fractions](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/UnsolvedConjecturesAboutEgyptianFractions/)

Comment: My answer goes to 11.

Comment: Argh.  No it doesn't!

Comment: So basically there isn't any concrete way to find the number of sets other than guessing and checking?

Answer (score 1):

Following the hints of others if you assume $a \le b \le c$ so $1/a \ge 1/b \ge 1/c$ we can conclude.

$1/2 > 1/a \ge 1/6$ so $2 < a \le 6$

then $1/b + 1/c = 1/2 - 1/a = (a-2)/2a$.

In all but $a = 5$ we have $(a-2)/2a = 1/d$ for some $d$.

So $1/b + 1/c = 1/d$.

Then $1/d > 1/b \ge 1/2b$ so $d < b < 2d$.

And $1/c = 1/d - 1/b = (b-d)/bd$  So $b-d|bd$  If $gcd(b-d,b) =1$ or $gcd(b-d,d)$ that doesn't happen.

That gives a strategy for trying to solve by brute force.

$a = 3$;

$d = 6$. $b=7,c=42;b=8,c=28;b=9,c=18;b=10,c=15;b=12,c=12$ are $5$ solutions.

$a =4$;

$d=4$.  $b=5,6,8$ and $c = 20,12,8$.  Three more solutions.

$a = 6$;

$d = 3$. $b = 6$ and $c = 6$.  One more solution.

$a = 5$ was the one where $(a-2)/2a = 3/10$ had no $d$.

$1/b + 1/c = 3/10$ so $3/10 > 1/b  \ge 3/20$ so $5\le b < 20/3 = 6 \frac 23$.  So $b = 5,6$.

so $1/6 + 1/c = 3/10$ so $1/c = 3/10 - 1/6 = 2/15$ so not a solution.

If $b$ = 5, $1/5 + 1/c = 3/10$ the $1/c = 1/10$ and $c = 10$. Is a solution.

So I have 10 solutions if I didn't make a mistake.  (11 *was* a mistake.)

Comment: Thank you for your hard work! I've only asked for the number of solutions, rather than a list, but thank you for your hard work!